# How to edit formset that has multiple forms inside related via generic foreign to the model of the current edit view?

Tags: python, django, formset, generic-foreign-key

In my recent project I had to create a generic model with a single file field, because the idea was to use multiple file uploads across multiple system models.

For this I created this generic model with generic foreign key and in the add view I create a formset with the extra = 1 field and in the template via jquery I add forms inside my formset.

In addition it works quietly, but I'm not able to adjust my edit view.

In my edit view I try it:

```
ModelGenericFormset = modelformset_factory(
        ModelsFileGeneric,
        form=AddModelsGenericForm
    )
query_files = ModelsFileGeneric.objects.filter(
        object_id=model_related_to_generic_model_with_file_field.id,
    )
files = ModelGenericFormset(queryset=query_files)
```

and in request.post:

```
files_form_set = ModelGenericFormset(
            request.POST,
            request.FILES
        )
for file_form in files_form_set:
                file = file_form.save(commit=False)
                setattr(
                    'upload_destination',
                    'path_to_upload'
                )
                file.content_object = model_related_to_generic_model_with_file_field
                file.save()
```

An observation:
As this model where the file field is is an extremely generic model (for this reason the use of the generic foreign key), I also need at runtime (in the save in view after the post) to change the upload_to attribute of the field (this already Was fixed and works ok).
I make this edition of the "upload_to" attribute because depending on the model to which I am sending multiple files, it will vary the path from where the files will be saved.

But in save of the edit view this error occurs:

**The ModelsFileGeneric could not be changed because the data didn't validate.**

And the error is in:

**file = file_form.save(commit=False)**

I don't know what to do anymore. Thanks!